# Polymer modeling template within template

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to create dropdown select (appearing if radio button is selected) in Polymer, that triggers another dropdown select on-iron-select.

All of this lives within a parent template:

```
<dom-module id="likes-cars">
  <template id="maintemplate">

    <paper-radio-button checked="{{likesCars}}" id="thebutton">I like cars.</paper-radio-button>



    <template is="dom-if" if="{{likesCars}}">
      <paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite car make">
        <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" on-iron-select="modelfunc">
          <paper-item>Make 1</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Make 2</paper-item>

        </paper-menu>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
    </template>



    <template id="menutemp">
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Your favourite car model">
      <paper-menu class="dropdown-content" >

        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{models}}"id="modelstemplate" >
          <paper-item>{{item}}</paper-item>
        </template>

      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </template>
  </template>
```

And my Polymer script once the iron-select occurs is:

```
    <script>

      Polymer({
        is:"likes-cars",

        modelfunc: function() {
          this.$.menutemp.model={}
          this.$.modelstemplate.model={models:["Model 1","Model 2"]}

        }
      });

    </script>
```

This results in the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'model' of undefined

What is the best way to select and model "modelstemplate" with an array passed in?

Do I need to model the template around it("menutemp") separately?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding how Polymer's data binding works a bit.

When you bind to something using the `[[property]]` or the `{{property}}` notation in a custom element, you're binding to the custom element's properties, no matter if you actually define the properties when calling the `Polymer()` function.

So when you say your `dom-if` and your `paper-radio-button` are bound to `likesCars` and that the `dom-repeat` is bound to `models` they're bound to `this.likesCars` and `this.models`.

So all you need to do in your `modelfunc` function is to set `this.models` to an array of Strings you want to show as items for the second menu. With this considered, the template enveloping the second menu is actually unnecessary.

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hisemezadu/1/edit?html,output) with a working example based on your code, I added a `selectedMake` property too so that you can actually set different arrays to the second menu depending on what was selected on the first menu.

I hope this helped